# Scheduling accuracy, Quartz.NET vs Rx 2.0

Tags: c#, system.reactive, quartz.net

Has anyone compared the scheduling accuracy (how close to the scheduled time the call actually occurs) between Quartz.NET and Reactive Extensions 2.0?

The only references I could find on the subject are [this thread which compares them as methods of scheduling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036581/quartz-vs-reactive-extensions) and the [Rx 2.0 RC announcement blog post which explains improvements in absolute timing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rxteam/archive/2012/06/20/reactive-extensions-v2-0-release-candidate-available-now.aspx) but neither really dwells on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to confess that I've not done the comparison, but I'd be willing to lay odds that the answer is that they have they same level of accuracy to within any margin that is going to be relevant to you!

Chris has the right idea, the limiting factor is the timer resolution of .NET (which, skipping a ton of detail, is basically ~15ms).

I can't see a good reason to choose between these libraries on the basis of their scheduling accuracy - both are reasonable given the above constraint. If ~15 ms is accurate enough, pick the one that delivers the API most suited to your needs.

If it isn't, you'll typically need to use native code. As soon as .NET is involved, deterministic RT behaviour exits stage left!

Comment: It may also be worth pointing out that, because of garbage collection, even 15ms accuracy is a best case scenario. In the worst case, there may be several seconds between the scheduled time and time of execution. :( But hey, every managed language has these kind of problems. :)

Comment: Christopher, while your discussion was educating, I will have to accept this answer because it's more "to the point". On this topic, do you guys know of any useful GC configuration or any other hack that would help?

Comment: I'm afraid not. There are even further factors to consider, like Jitting. Ngen (and the forthcoming native compilation options MS recently announced) could help with that though. Java has many GC switches and choices of VMs that have custom GCs, and there is a Java Rt spec - .NET doesn't have anything like this AFAIK.

Comment: Personally, I'd like to see something *like* ARC in .NET, but I doubt that's going to happen. I'm hopeful for the new native compilations, though. That could be a game changer.

Answer (score 4):

Seeing as how C# doesn't support real-time computing, the answer to this question is sort of irrelevant.

That being said, you should maybe use both. Rx provides the ability to implement your own schedulers, so you can certainly create one which uses Quartz.NET. If you go that route, you end up with all of the power of Rx, plus all of the power of Quartz.NET. Win win.

I would start with Rx, and add Quartz.NET whenever Rx doesn't meet all of your needs.

Comment: Christopher, thank you for the answer but it doesn't really point me in the right direction (unless you're trying to say you "don't know"). My concern is with regards to accuracy - i.e. which of the two frameworks is most likely to execute the job nearer the time I have scheduled it. I am not too bothered about the rest of the Quartz features. Any ideas on that? Also, is there a .NET compatible real-time platform? Thanks again.

Comment: There is not a real-time compatible .NET platform, as .NET *is* the platform, and it not real-time. This answer points you in one of two directions: Use Rx, and implement a Quartz scheduler for Rx if Rx doesn't meet your needs (about where or how something is scheduled, not accuracy for when something is executed). Or, don't use .NET at all because it is incapable of doing what you require.

Comment: To be perfectly clear, you are not concerned with accuracy. You are concerned with precision. Both libraries have the same accuracy, as they inherit the accuracy of the method they use for scheduling, which is in this case absolute time-based scheduling using the .NET platform. However, because both libraries have different paths to reach the actual scheduling mechanism, there exists the possibility that there are extra clock-cycles required to reach the scheduling mechanism. The difference between these clock cycles would be the difference in precision. So we're talking about clock cycles.